# How secured is password protected Memo?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, security, password, password-protection

I have Samsung Galaxy Star (GT-S5282) with 4.1.2. I wanted to store my bank and credit card information in password protected Memo. How secured is password protected Memo? Is there a way to crack the password of secured Memo? Is it possible for someone to root the phone and get the file/database of memo and get the details stored in password protected memo?

Comment: I would not recommend storing that sort of information on the device, either way, today's encryption is tomorrow's cracked!

Answer (score 2):

In general it's not a good idea to store sensitive data on your mobile phone, but back to your question.

[S Memo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sec.android.widgetapp.diotek.smemo) is storing your password as a clear text in `/data/data/com.sec.android.provider.smemo/databases/pen_memo.db > CommonSettings > PREF_APPLOCK_PIN` so if your device is rooted you can use Root Explorer to read it. 
Which means that this application is not secure. You can use [KeePasDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.keepass&) to encrypt passwords or other sensitive data. I am using it on my laptop and on my Android device.

Comment: Memo application I use is the default application that comes with device (The logo of application is "T" instead of "S"). Name of application is "Memo" and not "S Memo". Whatever you mentioned in your reply stands same for "Memo" too?

Comment: Check it. I have i9300 with S Memo.